# Change event doesn't trigger when Knockout updates value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an external javascript library which triggers on the change of a textarea, formats it, etc.

However, when KnockoutJS sets the value to the textarea, the change event isn't fired. [Simplified Fiddle of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/EZC9E/). Is it possible to fire the change event when Knockout updates the value of my textarea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than trying to force Knockout to work with change events you can setup a subscription on the underlying observable.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EZC9E/1/

```
this.text.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert('Text is changing to ' + newValue);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware of this solution. However, I am using a separate library which I don't want to modify for this purpose.

Comment: Eventually I went with this solution because frankly I couldn't find another way to achieve the desired outcome. It involved modifying the library which I don't like, but it works now and that is the most important thing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the javascript library, you might consider wrapping it into a **Custom Knockout Binding**. You may already need to use a custom binding for your library anyway, especially if you're using any `foreach` bindings that generate/destroy elements dynamically.

Once you've got the custom binding, you have a very convenient place to trigger 'change' from.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jQueryPluginFunctionCall = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // Apply jQuery plugin to textarea
        $(element).jQueryPluginFunctionCall();

        // Subscribe to the value binding of the textarea, and trigger the change event.
        allBindingsAccessor().value.subscribe(function () {
            $(element).trigger('change');
        });

        // Clean up jQuery plugin on dispose
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            // This will be called when the element is removed by Knockout or
            // if some other part of your code calls ko.removeNode(element)
            $(element).jQueryPluginFunctionCall('destroy');
        });
    }
}
```